# How does the kernel know some process is on the state TASK_RUNNING(running) or TASK_RUNNING(ready)?

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel, operating-system

I'm here to get some advice from all of you.

Regarding Linux task's process,

1. I'm confused a little bit, I think it is needed to distinguish the process state TASK_RUNNING(running) and TAKS_RUNNING(ready).

In other words, if I want to know which is the running task on CPU right now? 
How can I check that?

2. I tried to find some field for that inside task_struct. 
   But there is no one related to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux has a macro `current` that denotes the task currently running in the CPU executing the kernel code. [Here](https://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ/current)'s a doc with more elaborate explanation.